# To get tthe category url by using the category name

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

Is there any function in magento to get the category url by using the category name only. I know we can get the category url if we have the category id, but in my scenario, I have only the category name available. Any idea how to get this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that category names aren't unique, you could use this to get the URL of the first match:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($name, 'name');
if ($category->getId()) echo $category->getUrl() . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('core/url_rewrite_collection')->addFieldToFilter('request_path' array('like' => '%'.$category_name.'%'));
```

which basically gives you a collection sieved by the actual category url by the name, you might actually get the underlying products as the urls are like 'category/product' etc, but you can do sth like >>>

```
'like' => '%'.$category_name.'/' or 'like' => '%'.$category_name.'.html/'
```

in your collection field filter to get only the category url most likely.